# DateField.getYear() returning incorrect year

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have a Apps Script that I has been working perfectly for moving files into the correct folder.

```js
function organiseReceipts() {
  var receiptFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  var receipts = receiptFolder.getFiles();
  
  while(receipts.hasNext()) {
    var receipt = receipts.next();
    
    var destination = createFolder(receipt, receiptFolder);
    
    moveReceipt(receipt, destination, receiptFolder);
  }
}

function moveReceipt(receipt, destination, source) {
  destination.addFile(receipt);
  source.removeFile(receipt);
}

function createFolder(receipt, parent) {
  var createdDate = receipt.getDateCreated();
  var folderName = constructFolderName(createdDate);
  
  var matches = parent.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  
  if (matches.hasNext()) {
    return matches.next();
  }
  
  return parent.createFolder(folderName);
}

function constructFolderName(createdDate) {
  var year = createdDate.getYear();
  var month = createdDate.getMonth() + 1;
  
  var name = "" + year + "" + padNumber(month);
  
  return name;
}

function padNumber(number) {
  if (number < 10) {
    return "0" + number;
  }
  
  return number;
}
```

`organiseReceipts` is called once a day and moves files to a folder based on the metadata of the file. Files uploaded this year are ending up in incorrectly named folders as the year is coming out at `121`.

So I have a file uploaded on Friday `getCreatedDate()` is returning `Fri May 07 2021 13:18:02 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` which is correct, but when I call `getYear()` on that I get `121` where I would expect `2021`.

Am I doing something wrong? As I am not seeing what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [Date.getYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) is deprecated, it is returning the expected value:

> A number representing the year of the given date, according to local time, minus 1900.

> For years greater than or equal to 2000, the value returned by `getYear()` is 100 or greater. For example, if the year is 2026, `getYear()` returns 126.

As others said, use [Date.getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Date.getYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) was deprecated long ago. Use [Date.getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) instead.